# Declaring char array results segmentation fault in C programming language

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault, character

I was just creating simple implementation where I read input.txt file which has one line of code containing two numbers separated by space (e.g. 4 4).

I was trying to separate them by delimiting with space first.

And I was trying to use the first value as a size of char array.

However it keeps causing segmentation fault but I have no idea.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){

int number;
int i = 0;
char *token;
char buf[100];
int tempNum[2];

// Open file
FILE * fPointer;
fPointer = fopen("input.txt", "r");

// Read first line
fgets(buf, 1024, fPointer);
token = strtok(buf, " ");
number = atoi(token);

char charArray[number];


while(token != NULL){
    tempNum[i] = atoi(token);
    token = strtok(NULL, "\n");
    printf("%d\n", tempNum[i]);
    i++;
}
```

If I comment out "char charArray[number]" it does not cause segmentation fault. If I comment out only the while loop, it does not cause segmentation fault. But I cannot figure out why it is causing the segmentation in the first place. Please help.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What does the `1024` do?

Comment: If you want to make dynamic char arrays, you need to use malloc, as in char charArray[number], number is unknown at compile time. char charArray = malloc(number); then free(charArray);

Comment: Take a debugger to see what happens. The code is easy enough and you will learn how to debug your programs.

Comment: you are writing 1024 bytes into a 100 byte buffer, there for destroying the contents of 900+ bytes past the buf object.

Comment: @Nayfe, in the latest version of c, dynamic arrays are defined.

Comment: that is to say, you are writing not only to the buf object but also in the memory locations of the objects that immediately follow buf, like tempNum and fPointer, tha last of which is probably causing the segmentation fault.

Comment: You don't have any error checking. What if `fopen` fails? Or `fgets`? What if `number` is 0 or negative?

Comment: Not necessarily, @b'stard.  `fgets()` stores at most one byte more than it reads, so it will overrun the array bounds only if the input line contains more bytes than the buffer can actually hold, less one.  But the mismatch between the array declaration and the `fgets()` call is, indeed, pointless and risky.

Comment: I appreciate for all our helps. However I just found out by using gdb and the error message was "Program received signal SIGBUS, Bus error". Any ideas?

Comment: gdb does more than give you an error message. Use it to inspect the state of your program. Step through each line of code and see what happens.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie thanks, good to know if i need to switch back to pure C :)

Comment: "Bus errors are generally caused by applications trying to access memory that hardware cannot physically address. ", that is Linux Bus Error. you have overwritten the fPointer with some arbitrary data read from you file input.txt and that file pointer fPointer is trying to access God knows what memory address. maybe a negative one...

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUF_SIZE 1024
#define MAX_INPUT 2

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char *token = NULL;
    char *next_token = NULL;
    char buf[BUF_SIZE];
    long tempNum[MAX_INPUT] = { 0 };
    const char *delim = " ";
    char * end = NULL;

    // Init vars
    memset(buf, 0, BUF_SIZE);

    // Open file
    FILE * fPointer = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    if (fPointer == NULL) {
        return 1;
    }

    // Read first line
    if (fgets(buf, BUF_SIZE, fPointer) == NULL) {
        fclose(fPointer);
        return 2;
    }

    // Parse line
    token = strtok_s(buf, delim, &next_token);
    for (int i = 0;((i < MAX_INPUT) && (token != NULL)); i++){
        tempNum[i] = strtol(token, &end, 10);
        if (*end != NULL){
            printf("error in %s\n", token);
        } else {
            printf("%d\n", tempNum[i]);
        }
        token = strtok_s(NULL, delim, &next_token);
    }

    fclose(fPointer);
    return 0;
}
```